# Find a short path connecting vertices of a square

Tags: calculus

I have the following assignment:

> Given a square with side length equal $1$, find a set of lines connecting four vertices of this square. Sum length of the lines should be $\le 2.735$.

I think I could use some generalization of Fermat triangle problem, but I couldn't find any interesting material on generalizing it for more points. Also, I cannot just divide square into two triangles because it gives path longer than $2\sqrt2$ in any case.

Is there any theory that could be helpful in my case?

Comment: Hint: Steiner points. Or, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem